# function for return key not working in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, return

Here is my code.function is not running.even if i press return keyboard still appears on the screen.

```
  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    view.endEditing(true)
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the answer. Here txtemail is my textfield for which i am adding action for return key

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.txtemail.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
     self.view.endEditing(true)
     return false
}
```